# Transforming a set - Scala Coursera exercise

Tags: scala

I am working on the Coursera's Scala tutorials. One of the exercises asks to implement a map function to sets type that are defined as follows:
`type Set = Int => Boolean`. There was a stub for the function:

```
/**
* Returns a set transformed by applying `f` to each element of `s`.
*/
def map(s: Set, f: Int => Int): Set = ???
```

I thought that one can check if an element is in s, by doing the following:
`(x: Int) => s(x)`. Which I am thinking should be equivalent to whatever the definition of a set is. Thus, if we want to apply transformation on the set, we can do:
`(x: Int) => s(f(x))`. And so the definition of function is:
`def map(s: Set, f: Int => Int): Set = s(f(x))`. But this gives me some weird set if I try it on:

```
def map(s: Set, f: Int => Int): Set = (x: Int) => s(f(x))
  def toStringH(s: Set): String = {
    val xs = for (i <- -bound to bound if contains(s, i)) yield i
    xs.mkString("{", ",", "}")
  }
def printSet(s: Set) { println(toStringH(s)) }
val squaredSet = map((x: Int) => (x> -3 & x<3), (x:Int) => (x+1))
printSet(squaredSet)
```

So I am wondering where I went wrong. Thanks.

Comment: i think i got it. I may end up applying f to elements that are not originally in s. so i have to check for that

Comment: that formulation is incorrect as well, because it would be telling me whether the transformed value is in the original set. Not what I want

Answer (score 0):

I expect that you mean the `progfun1` course by Martin Odersky and its Week 2 task. I believe that generally there is no solution for this problem (it requires finding a reverse function for a given function which I doubt is really possible) and the course authors know about that. Thus they added an additional restriction that you probably missed (I highlighted the important part):

> Note that there is no direct way to find which elements are in a set. `contains` only allows to know whether a given element is included. Thus, if we wish to do something to all elements of a set, then we have to iterate over all integers, testing each time whether it is included in the set, and if so, to do something with it. ***Here, we consider that an integer x has the property -1000 <= x <= 1000 in order to limit the search space.***

Although it is a comment for the `forall` task it is in the same section and just a few paragraphs above the `map` task.

Comment: yes, correct. I am aware of that constraint. I rather had a problem with implementation. I figured it out now.